# phrase_prefix es search issue with single character

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data like 'Dipanshu S', 'Mohit Sharma' and 'Mohit Shakya' in my database and when i do a **ES** search query like :-

```
> "multi_match": {
>                  "query": "Mohit S",
>                  "type": "phrase_prefix",
>                  "fields": [ "name","nickname" ]
>                }
```

It gives me correct result 'Mohit Sharma' and 'Mohit Shakya' as it returns results with exact matching of first term 'Mohit' and returning all words starting with 'S' but when i do same search with query

```
"multi_match": {
                     "query": "Dipanshu S",
                     "type": "phrase_prefix",
                     "fields": [ "name","nickname" ]
                }
```

then it doesn't return any results because the word 'S' is not a word starting with character 'S' but its a complete word in itself in the data 'Dipanshu S'.

Mapping:

```
"name": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "fields": {
                            "caseInsensitive": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword_analyzer"
                            },
                            "fulltext": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "english_standard_edgengram_analyzer",
                                "search_analyzer": "english_standard_analyzer"
                            }
                        },
                        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
                    }
```

Analyzer:

```
"analyzer": {
                        "numeric_edgengram_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "edgengram_filter"
                            ],
                            "char_filter": [
                                "numeric_filter"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "keyword"
                        },
                        "lowercase_keyword_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "keyword"
                        },
                        "numeric_keyword_analyzer": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "char_filter": [
                                "numeric_filter"
                            ],
                            "tokenizer": "keyword"
                        },
                        "english_standard_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "english_standard_edgengram_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "edgengram_filter"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "english_standard_tokenizer"
                        }
                    }
```

So how to manipulate query to get results with *single character* words?

Comment: Show us your mappings

Comment: @AssaelAzran i have updated my question with mapping..please see

Comment: Settings are missing. (analyzers)  GET index/_settings

Comment: @AssaelAzran see now.